# How to avoid cycling call in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cyclic-reference

Title itself is enough for my question I guess. However I will explain further here, consider I have a two view controller A and B. A is base and it is pushing B, In one situation I want the A to be intimated from B when one button is clicked in View (B). Objective C is allowing to call directly A view if I have that instance. I think it is not a good practice to do that. How this case should be handled..

thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean _views_ or _viewControllers_?

Comment: Edited now View Controller :)

Comment: Are these inside a Navigation Contorller? Are you using the storyboard?

Comment: No I am not using story board, but I pushed using navigation controller

Comment: What's wrong with the back button?

Comment: sorry I am not getting what's in back button?

Comment: on the button click [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @Dhara Ya that I can do.. But I want a flag to be set in View A if that particular button is clicked

Comment: are you getting any error for this cycling call?

Comment: @sanjitshaw No but usually in windows.. We won't do that.. It will show error there

Comment: @Dhara I have a flag in View A which need to be set when a particular button is clicked in View B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF by 'A intimated from B' you mean you want to invoke the A that was initially responsible for pushing B, you just go back to A using the 'back' button, or in code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];
```

B doesn't need a pointer to A, the Navigation Controller has that, and B has a pointer to the Nav Controller because the Nav Controller sets B's `navigationController` property when it creates B.

If you need to set a property in A based on some action in B, you should use a delegate to do that.

In B, you make a property called `delegate`.

In A, when you create B, set it's delegate to A:

```
ViewControllerB* vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
vcB.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcB];
```

Then in B you can call back to A via the delegate before the pop:

```
[self.delegate sendMessageWithValue:someValue];
[self.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];
```

If you want to be extra-cautious, you can enclose the message-passing with:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sendMessageWithValue:)]) { ... }
```

To make this work without B knowing anything about A, other than that it is the delegate, B should declare a delegate protocol in the header (above `@interface`)

```
@protocol BDelegateProtocol
- (void) sendMessageWithValue:(int)someValue;
@end
```

When you declare the `delegate` property in B's `@interface`, specify the protocol it is expected to follow:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <BDelegateProtocol> delegate;
```

And in A's @interface header, advertise that you follow that protocol:

```
#import BViewController;

@interface AViewController:UIViewController <BDelegateProtocol>
```

This is the loose coupling you are after. B doesn't have to import A's header. It needs to know nothing about A other than that it conforms to B's protocol specification.

B does hold a pointer to A but it is a *weak* pointer. This is very important. If the delegate property was *strong*, B would increase the retain count of it's delegate by 1. If the delegate *also* holds a strong pointer to B, then neither of them can ever get deallocated. B will always have a retain count of at least 1 while A exists, and likewise A will always have a retain count of 1 while B exists: neither can be destroyed.

In this particular case that may not happen - A doesn't need to retain B as it's Nav Controller does - but it is a situation that can arise frequently as a delegate is very often the object that creates and owns the delegator. See "Use Weak References to Avoid Retain Cycles" in Apple's [*Practical Memory Management*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html)

Comment: I want a flag to be set in View A if that particular button is clicked, and I don't want to pop B for that case.

Comment: Is this how the cyclic reference is handled in Objective C with Delegate?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. One doubts.. Why do we need to create weak property in B, why not strong.

Comment: @Newbee, see "Use Weak References to Avoid Retain Cycles" in Apple's [_Practical Memory Management_](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html)